# ListView "onPopulate" Listener?

Tags: java, android, listview, listener, android-listview

I want to set an initial scrolled position to a ListView.

I thought I could do that by calling `list.setSelectionFromTop` after `adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated`, but of course the later only notifies the listview and the actual population may happen later.

Is there a way be notified when the listview has populated itself, so I can change the scroll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I tried `onFinishInflate` and `onSizeChanged`, but they didn't work. The later worked if the number if items changed, but not if the data was simply altered.

I then tried everything else, and the working methods to override were `onFinishInflate` and `onSizeChanged`. These are however also called on scrolling.

In fact, the last line in `ListView`s `layoutChildren` is a call to `invokeOnItemScrollListener`, so it turns out you don't have to extend `ListView`, but can simply set an `onScrollListener`.

No matter what solution you choose, you do however need to manually work around the problem of methods being called on scroll.